# Find main line (and its angle) in an image

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, computer-vision

I want to identify the main line in an image, and its angle (the lines running across the centre of the image). I start with an image (see link, https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfoHC.png) I have pre-processed using ImageJ (reduce noise, shadows and find edges). Any help would be much appreciated!

My code thus far,

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt
import matplotlib.pyplot as pltt
from scipy.stats import linregress

# Import image and convert to grayscale
im = cv.imread(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfoHC.png)
pltt.imshow(im)
pltt.show()
imgray = cv.cvtColor(im, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Convert grayscale image into binary mask
ret, thresh = cv.threshold(imgray, 200, 255, cv.THRESH_OTSU)

# Find contours in binary mask and plot binary mask
_, contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(thresh, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
window_name = 'Thresh'
pltt.imshow(thresh)
pltt.show()
cnt = contours[0]
M = cv.moments(thresh)
rows,cols = im.shape[:2]

# Fit line to identified contours in image and plot the results
[vx,vy,x,y] = cv.fitLine(cnt, cv.DIST_L2,0,0.01,0.01)
lefty = int((-x*vy/vx) + y)
righty = int(((cols-x)*vy/vx)+y)
line = cv.line(im,(cols-1,righty),(0,lefty),(0,255,0),2)
window_name = 'Image'
color = (0, 255, 0)
thickness = 9
imagee = cv.line(im, (cols-1,righty),(0,lefty),(0,255,0),2)
cv.imshow(window_name, imagee)
pltt.imshow(imagee)
pltt.show()
```

[image: Result from image pre-processing and edge detection using ImageJ]
[image: Result from binary threshold using Python 3.7 (OpenCV)]
[image: Result from my code above: Line fitted to contours]

Comment: Please post the original image too. I think the edge detection might not be the best first step.

Comment: you should debug the used contour (render it, have a look at it, ...). cnt = contours[0] is probably NOT the contour you are looking for. In your image you could try to find the BIGGEST contour. Or ignore the contour-thing at all and try to detect lines on your edges, instead of fitting a line.

Comment: Line fitting  works  in your  case  if the contour  you  filter is separated from  others, otherwise  your fitted line will  be  wrong. Also you are choosing  contour  with index 0 randomly... choose  the largest  contour  instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cnt 0 is probably not the right one to look at, as mentioned in the comments.

`cv.drawContours(im, contours, 0, (0,250,0), 3)` is useful to see that.

check out - 
https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html

also if you draw the "right" - biggest contour you would still probably get a weird fit - but it's no longer very far from the truth:

```
MAX = 0 
for i in range(len(contours)):
    if len(contours[i]) > MAX:
        MAX = len(contours[i])
        MAX_ind = i

cv.drawContours(im, contours, MAX_ind, (100,255,0), 3)
pltt.imshow(im)
```

[image: result]

Answer (score -1):

Use Opencv line segment detector  to be able  to  measure it's  Size.  take a look  at  cv2.createLineSegmentDetector()